# Disallowed URI chars used in my token

Tags: codeigniter

Take a look at this url:

```
http://localhost/foo/reset_password/bar@foobar.com/74ffb86822ca0a75e378e1eaa3a4a000fbf5eb1f6bc98d2ec789c59b2cc9cfc7e27e7489bfe59cfff04220c3e29f3869b8abc6f0a65ef170b9b9148d3619b2f9
```

This is the config:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

The url gives me this error -> `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.`

The longest ugly string in the url is timestamp + salt sha512 encoded, but I don't see any disallowed chars in there, any idea what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your sha hash... the problem is with the at "@" symbol. You cannot have an "@" symbol within the path portion of your URL.

You can escape it to %40

```
http://localhost/foo/reset_password/bar%40foobar.com/74ffb86822ca0a75e378e1eaa3a4a000fbf5eb1f6bc98d2ec789c59b2cc9cfc7e27e7489bfe59cfff04220c3e29f3869b8abc6f0a65ef170b9b9148d3619b2f9
```

should work... just unescape the email address on your end

Answer (score 0):

`bar@foobar.com`, specifically the `@`, in the URL is the reason for the error.